# Can't enable server push on Node.js server

Tags: javascript, node.js, html, browser, server

I'm trying to enable a server push on a Node.js server. Here's my code:

```
const http2 = require('http2');
const fs = require('fs');
const express=require('express');
var app=express();

const options = {
key: fs.readFileSync('./example/localhost.key'),
cert: fs.readFileSync('./example/localhost.crt')
};
http2.createServer(options,onRequest).listen(443);
function onRequest(request,response){
    var fileToPush='main.js';
    var push=response.push(fileToPush);
    push.writeHead(200);
    fs.createReadStream(path.join(__dirname, fileToPush)).pipe(push);
}
```

But when the client connects to the server, the command line on the server displays this error:

> response.push is not a function

How do I fix this?